# A variable that includes all paths in vbscript to search for a file

Tags: variables, vbscript

so im writing a dangerous file (with a warning of course)
i went to put a variable to include all paths of the system 
**(obviously before this there is a string to set the variable but thats what im searching for) ex : C:/User/x/file.txt" -> x = Every directory or path.**
is there a way for a variable to replace the x so that the computer doesnt have to scan a part of the computer but every directory at once?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60357152/edit) your question and add your code ?

Comment: well that is kind of it really? idk i was thinking of doing what you told me with the user variable but with a  path instead? Dim fso, strPath                                                            Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")                                                                    strPath = CreateObject("WScript.Network").Path                                                                                   x (from the question) = "& Path &"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain if this is what you're looking for, but here's a VBScript example that searches for all occurrences of a file under a parent folder, stores all the paths into a variable (v), then outputs the folder results where file was found under parent:

```
' File to locate under parent folder...
Dim file : file = "index.txt"
Dim parent : parent = "C:\Users\"

' Do the search for file under parent folder...
Dim StdOut : StdOut = ""
Dim StdErr : StdErr = ""
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    With .Exec(.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMSPEC% /C dir " & parent & file & " /S /B /A-D"))
        Do Until .StdOut.AtEndOfStream
            StdOut = StdOut & .StdOut.ReadAll()
            StdErr = StdErr & .StdErr.ReadAll()
        Loop
    End With
End With

' Parse StdOut search results and store paths in v...
Dim result, v : v = ""
For Each result In Split(StdOut, vbCrLf)
    If "" = v Then
        v = Replace(Replace(result, parent, ""), file, "")
    Else
        v = v & "|" & Replace(Replace(result, parent, ""), file, "")
    End If
Next
v = Split(v, "|")

' Output paths where file was found under parent...
Dim d
WScript.Echo "Found " & file & " in following folders under " & parent
For Each d In v
    WScript.Echo d
Next
```